# I can't wrap my head around this inequality (at least 2x for every y)

Tags: inequality

So if there exists 2x for every y, then that means y = 2x. Right?

But if there is AT LEAST 2x for every y, then the notation for that would be x >= 2y.

But... why? Why would it not be y <= 2x? For some reason I can not wrap my head around this.

EDIT: People aren't understanding this question, and I honestly don't know why. This is literally just translating an english sentence into an inequality.

This is where I saw the inequality:
http://www.purplemath.com/modules/linprog2.htm

"At a certain refinery, the refining process requires the production of at least two gallons of gasoline for each gallon of fuel oil."

"x: gallons of gasoline produced
y: gallons of fuel oil produced"

"Since I have to have at least two gallons of gas for every gallon of oil, then 
x > 2y."

Comment: This does not make any sense.  Can you clarify?

Comment: $\forall y, \exists 2x$ such that what ?

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify your question. As it stands it doesn't make any sense and as such I think it should be closed soon.

Comment: Clarify what? This is just translating an english sentence into math notation.

Answer (score 2):

Your first statement is incorrect: If there exists $2$ units of $x$ for every unit of $y$, then $2y = x$. One way to think about it is "I have twice as much $x$ as I do $y$." For example, if I have $2$ nickels for every penny I have and I have $3$ pennies, I must have $6$ nickels - i.e. $6 = 2(3)$, or $x = 2y$. This should clarify why the inequality is as it is.